# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre removeChild() y remove() en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo lo básico de `JAVASCRIPT`, por ahora me encuentro en lo de `html` y `dom`, específicamente en `Crear, modificar y eliminar nodos`, tengo el siguiente `html` básico para probar las distintas funcionalidades:

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
var texto =  document.createTextNode("Texto que se agregó por javascript");

p.appendChild(texto);

//encontrar el primer elemento de tipo p
var primer_p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

document.body.removeChild(primer_p); //Remueve el elemento p del documento html
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Ejemplos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Este elemento p será eliminado de la hoja html</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dom.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Antes de poner la siguiente línea, que es la que siguiere el tutorial que estoy siguiendo:

```
document.body.removeChild(primer_p);
```

Sin mirar el tutorial, primero miré los distintos métodos que tenía la variable `primer_p`, encontré el método `remove()`, así a secas y este también remueve el elemento.

```
primer_p.remove();
```

---

- ¿Ambos métodos hacen lo mismo?
- ¿De no ser así cuál es la principal diferencia entre ambos?

Comment: Esper oque te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36999675/11138725     y esta:https://stackoverflow.com/a/36998913/11138725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diferencia en la forma de hacer referencia al objeto. Si bien hiciste `document.body.removeChild(primer_p);` funciona por que el párrafo es un nodo de body. Pero, ¿Que pasa si agregamos un `<span>` y dentro el párrafo? Marcará un error por que el párrafo ya no es nodo directo de `body`, si no que está un `span` de por medio.

Ahora el método `remove()` elimina el elemento, sin importar el nivel al que se encuentre, es una referencia directa.

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
var texto =  document.createTextNode("Texto que se agregó por javascript");

p.appendChild(texto);

//encontrar el primer elemento de tipo p
var primer_p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
setTimeout( function() { primer_p.remove(); }, 3000 );
document.body.removeChild(primer_p); //Remueve el elemento p del
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Ejemplos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>
          <p>Este elemento p será eliminado de la hoja html</p>
        </span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dom.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```